# Add increasing number in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries

```
payloads = [{"a":20},{"b":20},{"c":20},{"d":20}]
```

and a static number, let's assume it is `2000`

I want to add this number in first dictionary and a `+1` in the following dictionaries
for e.g. 2001 in 2nd dict, 2003 in 3rd and so on ( depending upon the length of dictionary)

I tried:

```
t_no = 2000
for p in payloads:
    for i  in range(len(payloads)):
        p['no'] = t_no + i
        break
```

but it gives the same output in every dictionary

Output:

```
[{'a': 20, 'no': 2000},
 {'b': 20, 'no': 2000},
 {'c': 20, 'no': 2000},
 {'d': 20, 'no': 2000}]
```

Desired Output

```
[{'a': 20, 'no': 2000},
 {'b': 20, 'no': 2001},
 {'c': 20, 'no': 2002},
 {'d': 20, 'no': 2003}]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Your second `for` loop regenerate `i` from 2000 for each payload, making the `no` always the same (i.e. 2000). Try using `enumerate`: `for i, p in enumerate(payloads): p["no"]=t_no+i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
payloads = [{"a":20},{"b":20},{"c":20},{"d":20}]
t_no = 2000

for p in payloads:
    p['no'] = t_no
    t_no += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over them using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with `2000` as start.

```
>>> for idx, payload in enumerate(payloads,2000):
...     payload["no"]=idx
... 
>>> payloads
[{'a': 20, 'no': 2000}, {'b': 20, 'no': 2001}, {'c': 20, 'no': 2002}, {'d': 20, 'no': 2003}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following dictionary comprehension with dictionary unpacking `**`. I also use `str.rjust`. Here is the code:

```
>>> payloads = [{"a":20},{"b":20},{"c":20},{"d":20}]
>>> [{**v, 'no': int(str(list(v.values())[0]) + str(i).rjust(2, '0'))} for i, v in enumerate(payloads)]
[{'a': 20, 'no': 2000}, {'b': 20, 'no': 2001}, {'c': 20, 'no': 2002}, {'d': 20, 'no': 2003}]
>>>
```